# Redefining \toprule to default line thickness to use in tables

Tags: rules, booktabs

How can I change the width of a line in a table produced by `\toprule` to a default of 0.25em?

I know it would be something along the lines of `\renewcommand{\toprule}{??}` but what would be in the parameter braces?

Or is it easier to simply use `\toprule[0.25ex]` per table?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I assume that if you want to change the width of `\toprule`, you also want to change the width of `\bottomrule`. If that's the case, just issue the instruction

```
\setlength\heavyrulewidth{0.25ex}
```

in the preamble after `booktabs` is loaded.

Comment: Thanks. Can the same be done for `\midrule`?

Comment: @MrMorgan Yes, in this case change `\lightrulewidth`

Comment: @MrMorgan - Sure. The parameter is called `\lightrulewidth`. For `\cmidrule`s, the parameter is called, drumroll, `\cmidrulewidth`...

Comment: Note to future self: ``\cmidrule[thickness](shortening){colstart-colend}`` so a "local" change can be made with the first square-bracketed option.

Answer (score 7):

You should look at the definition of `\toprule` inside [`booktabs.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.sty):

```
\def\toprule{\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
  \@aboverulesep=\abovetopsep
  \global\@belowrulesep=\belowrulesep %global cos for use in the next noalign
  \global\@thisruleclass=\@ne
  \@ifnextchar[{\@BTrule}{\@BTrule[\heavyrulewidth]}}
```

After setting some predefined macro, `\toprule` uses `\@BTrule[\heavyrulewidth]` if you don't specify an optional argument. As such, you can redefine the `\heavyrulewidth` length (default is `.08em`; which will also affect `\bottomrule` and perhaps other rules). Better yet, make a new `\toprulewidth` and replace it inside `\toprule` using a patch:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,etoolbox}

\newlength{\toprulewidth}
\setlength{\toprulewidth}{0.25ex}
\patchcmd{\toprule}% <cmd>
  {\heavyrulewidth}{\toprulewidth}% <search><replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccc}
  \toprule
  A & B & C \\
  \midrule
  1 & 2 & 3 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```